# Firebase Authentication iOS 12 invalid token

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication, sms

I have an App that makes use of Firebase Authentication using phone SMS verification and recaptcha (no APNS)

The App works fine with the Authentication process if you are using iOS 11.4.1

However, if you are on iOS 12, then the Authentication process leads to an invalid token message

Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17048 "Invalid token." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Invalid token., error_name=INVALID_APP_CREDENTIAL}

currently using latest firebase ios SDK 5.9.0
latest version of xcode
iOS 12
latest Mac OS Mojave 10.14

I saw an earlier issue in June 2018 ( 3 months ago ) but not sure if it relates to our project
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/916

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk

Is there a solution around this or is this a Firebase iOS SDK bug?

Comment: @KENdi  Facing the same issue. Did you guys resolve it by any chance?

Answer (score 8):

Same Here!
I had the exact same problem, turned out that I forgot to set the **Identifier** to **Client** in the "**URL Types**" in the **Info** of the project.

[image]

Hopefully it would work for you.

Comment: Where is documented? according to Apple you should specify a reverse DNS string that incorporates your company’s domain and app name.

Comment: The Firebase documents stated the use of using URL Schemes here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth

But as you can see they have not updated that to the ios 12. but if you checkout the **sample codes of firebase on GitHub**, you'll surprisingly would see that the identifier field should be filled with **Client**.
Here is the GitHub link:
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk

Comment: This was my issue as well. Thanks for taking the time to post @sajedeNouri

Comment: It is still valid now? Firebase documentation doesn't states that https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/firebaseui , this answers should be updated

Comment: This did not solve the issue for us.

Answer (score 8):

It seems like there's a problem while using the `.p12` file for APNs in Firebase. I was facing the same problem and solved it changing the `.p12` certificate for the `.p8` instantly changing this, my app receives the SMS.

You can generate the `.p8` file in your Apple Developer account in the section `Keys` download the file and save it in a safe place. This new key also generates a `KeyId` that could be needed in the Firebase settings. Finally you would need the TeamId that corresponds to your Apple Developer account, you can found it in the Profile settings.

Hope this can help you.

Comment: In my case, using .p8 file, Team ID in general (firebase console -> project setting -> general -> iOS app) settings was wrong. Setting proper Team ID fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem when I want send OTP and get notifications, I created APN key on apple developer console then added it to firebase after that everything got well:

[image]

Answer (score -3):

I am also using same configuration that you describe in your question, and I am using this firebase methods it's perfectly running. so you can check your credential that you are using. Also check firebase docs.

```
Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (result, error) in

    if error == nil {

        guard let user = result?.user else {
            return
        }
        // do your stuff
    }
}
```