# Firebase & iOS 15 -Cannot Contact Recaptcha. Check Your Connection and Try Again

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, recaptcha

Last night I updated all of the pods. I'm using

```
Firebase (8.9.1)
Firebase/Auth (8.9.1)
Firebase/Messaging (8.9.1)
FirebaseAnalytics (8.9.1)
FirebaseCore (8.9.1)
FirebaseCoreOnly (8.9.1)
//... everything is 8.9.1
```

Today I submitted my app to App Review and I got a message about the Recaptcha not loading.

I submitted 2 apps and both of them couldn't pass the Recaptcha in iOS 15 but on my end I have a device that runs iOS 13 and another device that runs iOS 14 and the Recaptcha works fine for both apps. I even it ran it on the simulator and the Recaptcha worked for both apps. I have the test phone number that use to login in registered as a test number in Firebase. I can login with the number without any issues.

Even though it's been a few months since my last AppStore update this never happened with any of my previous submissions. I never changed any of the code between my last update and today.

I'm wondering is this an iOS 15 issue?

> Guideline 2.1 - Performance - App Completeness
>
> We discovered one or more bugs in your app.
>
> Specifically, we still encountered an error message at the login.
> Please see the attached screenshot(s) for your reference.
>
> Review device details:
>
> - Device type: iPhone and iPad
> - OS version: iOS 15.1
>
> Next Steps
>
> Please run your app on a device to reproduce the issues, then revise
> and submit your app for review. If at first you're unable to reproduce
> the issue, try the following:
>
> - For new apps, uninstall all previous versions of your app from a device, then install and follow the steps to reproduce.
> - For app updates, install the new version as an update to the previous version, then follow the steps to reproduce.
>
> If we misunderstood the intended behavior of your app, please reply to
> this message in Resolution Center to provide information on how these
> features were intended to work.

Here is the screenshot that they sent. It was the same for both apps.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

After deploying several new builds which all got rejected by the App Review team, I finally passed.

I followed [this github](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/1655). Look for the answers by @rignaneseleo and @diegogarcia). They both say to set this to `.unknown` as in `Auth.auth().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: .unknown)`

In AppDelegate I have:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        
        Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
        Messaging.messaging().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: MessagingAPNSTokenType.prod)
        Auth.auth().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: .unknown) // Setting this to .unknown is what seems to have helped
}
```

And I followed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53089688/4833705) by @sajedeNouri

> set the Identifier to Client in the "URL Types" in the Info of the
> project.

[image]

Comment: Hey that's me! Just encountered this error too... I guess I solved my own issue?

Comment: @DiegoGarcia lmao, that’s funny. But yes, your github answer definitely works. I got rejected 3x before adding `.unknown`. After I added, the recaptcha worked and I got approved.

Comment: I had the same problem but your solution did not work for me. Instead, completely recreating the native `ios` project helped

Comment: @highwaychile sorry that it didn’t work for you. I wonder why?I have about 5 projects that use this same code and they all work for me. What do you mean by `recreating the native iOS project`?

Comment: I did both of these things and we still got rejected and app review had the same issues (we had previously been flying through app review no problem). I wonder if this isn’t an issue on our end at all but Google’s

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw yeah this is a strange issue. I've pushed several updates with this same code to the App Store and it worked. I actually have several apps that use this code and I haven't had any issues. I think that this is problem with Firebase. I'm not sure why the code isn't working for you. Try the same code agin but use `.prod` to see what happens. eg. `Auth.auth().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: .prod)`

Comment: This is going to sound silly.... but all the of screenshots app review provides shows no wifi signal in the status bar. I'm wondering if this app reviewer is testing our app with no internet connection. I almost refuse to believe that's the case because it would be so ridiculous... yet 3 rejections in a row and each time the screenshots show that. What do you think: https://ibb.co/4SFNx9Z

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw Looking at your screenshots, the very first thing that I notice is that you don't show any error messages so you have no idea where to even start. Maybe the issue is something else. This is an opinion but in your situation I think you need it. First thing that you should do is get a list of all of the `FireAuthErrors` I listed them here https://stackoverflow.com/a/61571172/4833705. 2nd thing that you should do is is in the `.verifyPhoneNumber()...}` callback you need to read the error that was returned. Here is the code for it

Comment: @LanceSamaria We do show error messages, this was simply a screenshot they provided before the error occurs. This has all been working fine in production for almost a year now too... baffled by all of this. Will report back if we learn anything new

Comment: `PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumTextField.text!, uiDelegate: nil) { [weak self](verificationID, error) in if let error = error { if let errorCode = AuthErrorCode(rawValue: error._code) { } } // ... }`. 3rd, once you get the `errorCode` you need to display it as a error message somewhere on that screen. Just simply display `Error: \(errorCode)`. Display it in red, probably right underneath the phoneNumTextField. However you create your UI create your UI, but atleast if there is another AppReview problem when they send the screenshot back you'll know what exact FB error

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw when I ran into the issue with AppReview they sent me a screenshot and I saw the errorCode so I was able to dig further. I think you need to find out the exact errorCode causing your issue. It will give you more insight on where to go

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Enums/AuthErrorCode

Comment: I've confirmed that App Review did not even have an internet connection, so this is why they weren't able to connect to ReCaptcha, and why we weren't able to get error codes sent to our analytics collection.

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw Congrats! How was you able to find that out? That’s a really silly mistake for them to make

Comment: We added a ton of analytics to our backend to figure out exactly what was going on, they reviewed the app, and no analytic events occurred at all, implying they never even connected to back end. We informed them of this and the app update got approved without even going back into review.

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw You should post that as an answer. I’m sure there are other people who got rejected for that same reason.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I got the same error message from the reviewer, when I looked at the backend, an account was created with the reviewer email, but the phone was not verified. making this feature as an optional will not help as well, as long as the error is producible on your app, it will be rejected.
It is not a network issue from the reviewer side, however, it is triggered by them in the sandboxing environment, silent push notification is one of the major causes of this issue, if that is the case with you, you need to enable push notification capability in xCode even if you’re not using it. create the APN key, and upload it to firebase, and add the URL schemes exactly as in your GoogleService-Info.plist