# Firebase - .webInternalError: Indicates that an internal error occurred within a SFSafariViewController or WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I submitted 2 apps to the App Store. Both apps aren't loading the recaptcha but one of the apps keeps giving them a problem. The error returned is:

> case .webInternalError:
>
> Indicates that an internal error occurred within a
> SFSafariViewController or WKWebView.

As of yesterday I have the most recently updated pods. They are using iOS 15.2 to login. The odd thing is I have zero issues when I use the test phone number that I gave them (it's added in the Firebase console) and when I try on my end using iOS 14 and iOS 13, I have no issues with any other phone number.

I have no idea what to do at this point.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the issue was, but once I followed this [github](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/1655), the problem was no more. Look for the answers by @rignaneseleo and @diegogarcia.

They both say to set this to `.unknown` as in `Auth.auth().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: .unknown)`

In AppDelegate I have:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        
        Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
        Messaging.messaging().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: MessagingAPNSTokenType.prod)
        Auth.auth().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: .unknown) // Setting this to .unknown is what seems to have helped
}
```

And I followed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52547951/firebase-authentication-ios-12-invalid-token/53089688#53089688) by @sajedeNouri